# Plotly lightweight aggregated histogram

Tags: python, plotly, histogram

I have a dataframe with ~500k entries. I am using [`px.histogram`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.histogram) to do some histograms and save the plots in html format. The files weight something like 10 MB, which points to the fact that Plotly is saving each individual entry to build the histogram when the html file is loaded. Is it possible to tell Plotly to simply sum the data in each bin so the file is not so heavy?

This is my code:

```py
fig = px.histogram(
    df,
    x = 'whatever',
    color = 'whatever else',
)
fig.write_html(
    'plot.html',
    include_plotlyjs = 'cdn',
)
```

Comment: You could pre-compute the histogram and then plot a bar chart : use [`numpy.histogram()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram) to bin the data in x and count the number of values in each bin, and from there just use `px.bar()` or `go.Bar()` to plot the aggregated data. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62703660/2529954